# MonoMac - Game Center

Tags: c#, .net, mono, game-center, monomac

Are the Game Center APIs implemented in MonoMac?

If not, is there a recommended path for creating C# bindings for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open source MonoMac does not include bindings for GameKit (or the more recent frameworks included in Lion or Mountain Lion).

`bmac`, like the MonoMac equivalent to MonoTouch's `btouch`, are the same tools that we (Xamarin) use to create bindings - everything is possible using them.

**UPDATE:** The new [Xamarin.Mac](http://xamarin.com/mac), a superset of MonoMac, includes bindings for GameKit (and other frameworks previously only available in MonoTouch).

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. If I get a decent binding working, I'll make sure to send a pull request to MonoMac. Is anyone really working on MonoMac right now?

Comment: Well, looking at the GameKit reference for mac, it is almost identical to iOS. Any way I could get the source for MonoTouch.GameKit as a starting point?